# Proving intersection and union of a particular indexed set

Tags: analysis

I'm having trouble proving these, can anyone help?

The question is as follows:

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $A_n = \lbrace{ k \in \mathbb{Z} ; k^2 <= n}\rbrace$

Prove that:

1) $\bigcap A_n$ = $\lbrace 0, 1, -1 \rbrace$

2) $\bigcup A_n = \lbrace ...,-2,-1,0,1,2,...\rbrace = \mathbb{Z}$

Can anyone show me how to prove these?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For $1)$ what is $q$ ? And if $n\geq 0$, then $\bigcap_{n}A_n$ is $\{0\}$. To have your equality, you must take $n\geq 1$. Any way, in both case if you know the definition of $\bigcup_{n}A_n$ and $\bigcap_{n}A_n$, the claim should almost follow.

Comment: Sorry, it's n, (typo, edited it right now). Yes, I know the definition but that is just the first step of the proof, how do I proceed after that?

Comment: But is $n\in\mathbb N$ or $n\in \mathbb N^*$ ? Because if $n\in\mathbb N$ the first question is wrong.

Comment: I'm taking the set to be the set of positive integers

Comment: Please, be clear ! What is your definition of positive integer ? To me $0$ is a positive integer.

Comment: +ve integers excluding zero = set of natural numbers

Comment: Zero is not included

Answer (score 1):

1) The fact that $\{-1,0,1\}\subset \bigcap_{n}A_n$ is clear. For the converse inclusion, if $k\in \bigcap_{n}A_n$, then $k^2\leq n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N^*$. In particular, $k^2\leq 1$, and thus $k\in\{0,1,-1\}$.

2) The fact that $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\subset \mathbb Z$ is clear. Let $k\in\mathbb Z$. In particular, $k^2\in  A_{k^2}$. The claim follow.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. Let $$x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$
   Then, $x\in A_n$ *for every* $n\in\mathbb{N}$. What can you get from here?
2. Let
   $$x\in\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$
   Then, *there exists some* $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in A_{n_0}$. What can you get from this?

**Edit:**
After your request:

For the first: let $$x\in\bigcap A_n$$ Then, as you said, $x\in A_1$, so $x\in\{-1,0,1\}$. So $$\bigcap A_n\subseteq \{-1,0,1\}$$ Now, since $$\{-1,0,1\}\subseteq \bigcap A_n$$ it comes that $$\bigcap A_n=\{-1,0,1\}$$ Try to use somthing similar for the second. The most usual way to show that two sets are equal is to use the following:

> $$A=B\Leftrightarrow A\subseteq B\text{ and }B\subseteq A$$

Comment: for the first one, A1 is the subset of A2, and so forth, that ,makes A1 the smallest set whose elements are contained in all of the sets. I know this but how do I formalise this argument. Similarly, for the union, it the set will get bigger and bigger to include all of the integers, but again, how to write it is what I don't get.

Comment: I edited the answer after you request. Try the second question and inform us about your proggress! :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try and get back. Thanks a bunch! :)